# django: ModelForm access instance of new object

Tags: django, django-forms

I wanted to ask if there is a way to access instance id in ModelForm save method. (Need an object in order to add some extra data).

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super(MyForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    print instance 
    return instance
```

And in all cases I am getting instance before it's saved in database (so it does not have an id and I can't attach objects to it)

Comment: It's a bit strange. When I do print kwargs it says {'commit': False}. interesting why

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to override the ModelForm `save()` function. Instead, it's better to call save with `commit=False`. [The Django docs explain this in depth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method), but here's a quick example:

```
new_object = form.save(commit=False)
new_object.name = 'Whatever'
new_object.save()
```

By calling save with `commit=False`, you get an object back. You can do whatever you want with this object, but make sure to save it once you make your changes!

Comment: Well the thing is that I am not processing this form in my view. It's more like xadmin form, I have added for a specific model. So in general I can only tweak all form methods.. but can't access views

Comment: Hm, well in that case sorry my answer wasn't helpful. Does the admin library you're using offer for class overrides and registrations, [as the Django admin does](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12321130/4256689)?